# Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry

I recently started having problems deploying new revisions to Google Cloud Run.
I'm following the same old routine for deployment I have used for a couple years.

When I am in the gcloud cli, it tries to send traffic to an old revision and fails.

So I tried deploying from the web console and it gives me this error: "The service account, *****************@developer.gserviceaccount.com, does not exist."

I haven't modified any permissions, so that seems odd to me.

One other oddity: something is trying (and failing?) to create revisions to the tune of 6 per minute.  It's like its failing, so it is on an infinite-retry spiral of death.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check in IAM if this service account still exist or was it deleted?

Comment: My guess is that someone disabled an API or service. Go thru the requirements section of the docs and make sure that all required APIs and services are enabled for all services that you use.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies. I couldn’t find any issues in IAM or with disabled APIs…

I solved it by creating a new Google Run service. The old one couldn’t load new revisions (apparently because of something to do with the service account), but the same service account worked fine on an altogether new service.